# SATA to eSATA and back again using an old PC case

Tags: hard-drive, sata, esata, case-mods

Simple question, will this work?

I want to house hard drives in an old case and use the power supply in the old case to power the drives.  Then I want to use two of these:

[Newegg SATA to ESATA bracket](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817198044N82E16812200500&gclid=CPeD0cO6xLgCFeRj7AodnE0AvA)

One in each PC and use an eSATA cable to connect the cases (one SATA end in the old case plugged into the drive and the other SATA end plugged into the motherboard on the PC).

In essence, I am trying to make a poor mans version of this, minus the USB connections:

[ICY DOCK MB561US-4S-1 Aluminum / Plastic 4 x 3.5" USB2.0 & eSATA Aluminum HDD Enclosure for Mac & PC](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817198044)